# code not working inside if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I am facing problem in considering the if/else statements in the following piece of code. Actually I want to tell my user if the word from the file is not found my code must shows an error message else my code must go to show a new form, here's my code:

```
    public void searchGlossary(String word)
    {
        StringBuilder description = new StringBuilder(512);
        string descLine;
        using (StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("C:/Users/--- /Desktop/--- .txt"))
        {
            string line;
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith(word, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    // At this point we've already read the keyword and it matches our input

                    // Here we start reading description lines after the keyword.
                    // Because every keyword with description is separated by blank line
                    // we continue reading the file until, the last read line is empty 
                    // (separator between keywords) or its null (eof)
                    while ((descLine = reader.ReadLine()) != string.Empty && descLine != null)
                    {
                        description.AppendLine(descLine);
                    }
                    //descbox.Text = description.ToString();
                    isfound = true;
                    DomainExpertForm form = new DomainExpertForm(keyword, description.ToString());
                    form.Show();
                    break;
                }

            }

            if (isfound == false)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Matches found for Word " + word, "Domain Expert Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

        }


    }
```

The problem is that if the word is not found it always shows me form instead showing an error message. What's the problem and the solution can somebody help me I am new c#!

Comment: initialise isFound to false (bool isFound = false) before StringBuilder.

Comment: Where is "isFound" defined? Try defining it at the beginning of the method and initialise it with false.

Comment: Btw, you don't need to test boolean variables in if statements, you can simply do this `if (!isfound)`

Comment: I have tried it no success

Comment: Are you trying to find `word` in a _line_ of your file?  Or the entire file?

Answer (score 5):

You should declare and initialise `isFound` with `false` at the beginning of your method:

```
public void searchGlossary(String word)
{
  var isFound = false; 
  StringBuilder description = new StringBuilder(512);

  ...
}
```

Comment: Not only that, you should really *declare* it there.  It makes no sense for it to be declared at a higher scope.

Answer (score 0):

what i need was to check if the required word was found and if not I want to show the Error Dialogue so here is my solution:

```
    I simply checked the length of the found string; if its ==0 i show up an error message as:

        if (description.ToString().Length==0)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Matches found for Word " + word, "Domain Expert Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

and here I go found this solution myself!